# Will I receive my Ether? Transferred to my wallet while the Ethereum wallet was downloading

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, wallets, cpp-ethereum

So I was super excited to get the ethereum wallet downloaded, I followed all the steps. As I set it up, after the part where you set your password it prompted me to fund my wallet with ether. I then went to my poloniex account and sent all my ether from that account to the address provided in the setup of my ether wallet. After it was "successfully" sent from poloniex I went back to the wallet, hit next, and then the next screen came up: "downloading the blocks." I had assumed that the deposit screen was the last screen in my setup. My question is, will I see my ether in my account after the blocks have been downloaded and the wallet is fully set up? From my polo account, it says that my ether has been successfully sent, but obviously I can't see it because the blocks are downloading (my wallet is being set up)

PS,
This is my first time downloading this ethereum wallet. Appreciate your assistance in answering my question.

-Noob

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your Ether will be shown only after full sync of the recent blocks. If you want to confirm if you have received the ether in that address, you can confirm it in etherscan.io. Go to that site, paste your new address, and if you see the balance updated, it will be shown in your wallet too.